# Выдает ошибку Undefined variable: users

Tags: php, laravel

Здравствуйте, уже 2 день мучаюсь но всю зря.
Вот код код ошибки

> (2/2) ErrorException
>   Undefined variable: users (View: D:\OpenServer\OpenServer\domains\project.loc\resources\views\home.blade.php)

а вот и сам код

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">All Users</div>

            <div class="panel-body">
            @foreach($users as $user)
                <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <img src="{{$user->avatar}}">
                            {{$user->name}}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="{{route('message.read', ['id'=>$user->id])}}" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Send Message</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

@endsection

Контролер!!!!

```
 <?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Nahid\Talk\Facades\Talk;
use Auth;
use View;

class MessageController extends Controller
{
    protected $authUser;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        Talk::setAuthUserId(Auth::user()->id);

        View::composer('partials.peoplelist', function($view) {
            $threads = Talk::threads();
            $view->with(compact('threads'));
        });
    }

    public function chatHistory($id)
    {
        $conversations = Talk::getMessagesByUserId($id);
        $user = '';
        $messages = [];
        if(!$conversations) {
            $user = User::find($id);
        } else {
            $user = $conversations->withUser;
            $messages = $conversations->messages;
        }

        return view('messages.conversations', compact('messages', 'user'));
    }

    public function ajaxSendMessage(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            $rules = [
                'message-data'=>'required',
                '_id'=>'required'
            ];

            $this->validate($request, $rules);

            $body = $request->input('message-data');
            $userId = $request->input('_id');

            if ($message = Talk::sendMessageByUserId($userId, $body)) {
                $html = view('ajax.newMessageHtml', compact('message'))->render();
                return response()->json(['status'=>'success', 'html'=>$html], 200);
            }
        }
    }

    public function ajaxDeleteMessage(Request $request, $id)
    {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            if(Talk::deleteMessage($id)) {
                return response()->json(['status'=>'success'], 200);
            }

            return response()->json(['status'=>'errors', 'msg'=>'something went wrong'], 401);
        }
    }

    public function tests()
    {
        dd(Talk::channel());
    }
}
```

Спасибо!!!

Comment: Где код контроллера?

Comment: +1 к предыдущему оратору.
У вас тут явно не определена переменная $users, по которой идет цикл. Надо смотреть контроллер, нет ли где ошибки.

Comment: @Andrewus Я редактировал вопрос

Comment: А где у вас переменной(массиву) **$users** данные-то присваиваются? У вас кроме как в цикле, ни где эта переменная не упоминается!

Comment: @Visman в HomeController.php `    public function index()
    {
        $users = User::all();
        return view('home', compact('users'));
    }
`

Comment: Хм, а как он относится к представленному MessageController?

Comment: @Visman Я нашел проблему в  HomeController.php надо было добавить use App\User; и

use Nahid\Talk\Live\Broadcast; Спасибо!!!